# How to add 3D drawable effect to layout in GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout, grid

I'm building a GridView that fills itself (with 'tiles') by using a custom GridAdapter. Now I'm trying to add a effect to each tile, the effect is shown in the red circle:

[image]

This is what I have now:

[image]

The layout file, tile.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:background="@drawable/tile_background" 
android:id="@+id/frameItem"
android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tile_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/big_image"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile_title" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/tile_arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile_image"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="5px"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tile_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Categorie"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textColor="@color/purple"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:padding="5px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I literally have no idea how to implement the '3D effect' and if it is even possible.

I tried it with adding an image to the layout file. But that didn't work out for me, I couldn't get it right. It also felt like it wasn't the right way to do it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check [this library](https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-swipecards-view). It's not exactly what you want but you can do whatever you want by looking at it.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using [9-patch files](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html). Using this online [Nine-patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html).